# Failed to find runtime clr.dll to use sos

Tags: c#, debugging, clr, windbg, sos

I have simple console application (target framework 4.5.2):

```
using System;

public class SosTest
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creation of foo");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var n1 = new Foo();
        var n2 = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("Allocated objects");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to invoke GC");
        Console.ReadKey();
        n2 = n1;
        n1 = null;
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I want to see state of managed heap. I do following steps:

1. Open windbg
2. Open exe file of my program with windbg's "open executable" command
3. Perform command to load sos `.load MicrosoftNet\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll`
4. Perform command to see state of heap `!eeheap -gc`

But during last command I get following message:

> Failed to find runtime DLL (clr.dll), 0x80004005
>   Extension commands need clr.dll in order to have something to do.

Why does command `!eeheap -gc` fail?

If it will help it is result of `lm` command:

```
0:000> lm
start    end        module name
00be0000 00be8000   ConsoleApplication1   (deferred)            
734c0000 73519000   MSCOREE    (deferred)             
74c20000 74d00000   KERNEL32   (deferred)             
753d0000 75571000   KERNELBASE   (deferred)             
77d80000 77f03000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure you are doing it right way or not, but i used to do it with the following command:

```
sxe ld clrjit; g
```

and after that write:

```
.loadby sos clr
```

the `sxe ld clrjit` notifies debugger when **clrjit module** is loaded, the `g` flag is for continuing execution and `.loadby sos clr` will load **sos debugger** from location where it finds **clr.dll**

I once watched the following the following two plural-sight courses on **C# Internals** by [Bart de Smet](https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/bart-desmet) and i found them great for understanding the insights of c# and clr:

[C# Language Internals - Part 1](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-language-internals)

[C# Language Internals - Part 2](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-language-internals-part2)

Comment: The `.loadby` command needs the `clr` module to work. That's usually loaded earlier than `clrjit`, so `sxe ld clr` might suffice.