# Failed to find runtime DLL (coreclr.dll), 0x80004005

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windbg

I am trying to analyze the dump file of a .net core 2.1 project on WinDbg x64 for figuring out memory leaks in the application.

I Ran ->
`.load C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.28\sos.dll`

Post this i tried to run

`!verifyHeap`

which returns me an error saying failed to find runtime dll coreclr. I tried to do

`.loadby sos coreclr`
which is also giving me error "Unable to find module coreclr"

I have these SDKs on my machine :

[image: List of SDKs]

*I have double checked and coreclr.dll is present in the same folder as sos.dll
Also windbg x64 works for the dump of a .net core 3.1 application and i was able to run commands*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346885/failed-to-find-runtime-clr-dll-to-use-sos

Comment: Try downloading the SDK : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @OlivierRogier it works for 3.1 .net core project so i am sure i am not missing out on any steps

Comment: `.loadby` needs `corecrl` to be present in the list of modules. Check `lm` whether it is loaded. Sometimes it might be relocated and thus renamed.

Comment: Also I doubt you can't use 2.1.28 to debug 2.1.816. For .NET framework it always needed to have the exact mscordacwks version

Answer (score 0):

I just started using WinDbg yesterday and ran into this same iusse today.

I found the answer in this article:

https://www.graymatterdeveloper.com/2020/02/14/windbg-launch-net-executable/

Simply put, run these 3 commands:
sxe ld clrjit
g
.loadby sos coreclr